# Replicating document.write behaviour

Tags: javascript

In the last couple of weeks i'm trying to replace document.write with my own implementation so i can load some third party js that uses it asynchronously.
i have made some progress but document.write can be very complex.
i'm using "DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument() " to create an empty html document to parse the initial html and than i'm appending the nodes to the real dom , and in some of those nodes there are script tags that uses document.write . 
To handle those calls at first i tried to parse that html again and append it after the script tag that initiated the call but this case doesn't handle partial html , for example:

```
document.write("<di");document.write("v></div>";
document.write("<scri");document.write("pt src='example.com></script>");
```

i can push all the html to a buffer and flush it when the script is done but i will also need to handle many more cases like:

```
document.write("<div id='test1'></div>");document.getElementById("test1");
```

which will not exist on my case.

any ideas how to handle document.write reliably ?

BTW:
will the `Node.querySelectorAll("*");` property return the nodes in the same order as they are in the dom reliably ? for example:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll("*"); -->
<body>
    <div id="test1">
        <div id="test2">
            <img id="img1">
        </div>
        <img id="img2">
    </div>
</body>>
```

will always output --> test1->test2->img1->img2

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  thanks , fixed it

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the flow of who when what...

Comment: A DOM Nodes tree is reliable as per https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I’m trying to load scripts that uses document.write async , so I need to replace document.write ( will clear the document if not ) so I need to parse the HTML and insert it dynamically and I’ve encountered some issues as I mentioned above

Comment: Then you have taken on a heck of a task. Replicating the behavior of document.write isn't that easy, though, as you are always going to run into a lot of limitations. I'm also working on such a thing, and that has already reached more than 2.5k lines of code although I'm not even done yet. So if you intend to continue on this avenue, you should expect a lot more work, especially if you intend to implement any sanity checks along with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making document.write async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842531/making-document-write-async?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making document.write async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842531/making-document-write-async)

Comment: You should rewrite the third-party JS instead if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your question, but I can make polyfill of document.write with document.innerHTML.

Here's the code

```
document.innerHTML += text;
```

Comment: Won’t work , try it with partial HTML and it will just ignore it